# Cannot import module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Here's the directory structure

```
.../Desktop/scratch/abc/greet.py
```

I have my import code `module.py` in abc

```
.../Desktop/scratch/module.py:
```

```
import sys 
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\scratch")
import abc.greet
```

**I have created empty init file in abc and greet folders.**

But when i run this code then error be like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1519, in _find_and_load_unlocked AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "module.py", line 4, in <module>
    import abc.greet ImportError: No module named 'abc.greet'; abc is not a package
```

I don't understand why this happens? How is abc not a module when I have created the init file and also added the scratch directory to the search path.

PS: `greet.py` just contains a method `hello` which prints "hello world", if this info is of any use.

Comment: Okay, you have a `abc\greet.py` file and you say there's `greet` folder... which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Python already has a module named [abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). Choose a different name.